# Cannot Read Property of Undefined in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this getData method to grab some statistics from an external API:

```
 getData = (name=this.state.name) => {
    console.log('Name', name);
    fetch(`https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/${name}/?convert=USD`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(results => {
        this.setState ({
            marketdata: results[0]
        })
    }) 
}
```

If i console log the results[0] it looks like this:

`{id: "bitcoin", name: "Bitcoin", symbol: "BTC", rank: "1", price_usd: "10908.7", …}`

if i try to render one of the values like this:

`<p>{marketdata.price_usd}</p>`

the page will load--i can see the actual value on the page, and then the error hits the screen:

`Cannot read property 'price_usd' of undefined`

Could this be something related to how i'm using the lifecycle methods?

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(this.props.value !== nextProps.value) {
        this.setState({value: nextProps.value });
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
      const {value, name} = this.state;
      this.getName(value);
      this.getData(name);
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) { 
    if(this.state.value !== prevProps.value) {
        this.getName(this.state.value);
    }
    if(this.state.name !== prevState.name) {
        this.getData(this.state.name);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I'd say so, is it possible for the ```name``` property on state could go undefined at any lifecycle event?

Comment: that was the problem, i was passing in a dummy value for the 'value' and needed to do the same for the 'name'.  thanks for that insight!

Comment: Algood, happy to help

Comment: ugh..actually it didn't work--it worked once and now getting same issue every time...

Comment: How about this: "lift" ```getData``` method to parent component, the one that passes ```name``` and ```value``` as props. Run ```getData``` on the parent component's lifecycle event (```ComponentDidMount``` etc) and then pass results down as props?

Comment: ok...think i got it now..lol...sorry to bug you man...but thanks again. I needed to set the initial values to a default variable on mount--as they were getting set to blank from my initial declared state